# ValueError: Could not interpret value `female_height` for parameter `x` when trying to plot certain rows in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I have a big dataframe that consists of male and female shoe sizes. I am currently trying to plot size versus height for male and female separately. I have tried to slice the data and stored it in different variables, however I get an error when I try to plot it.

[image]

Here I tried to obrain rows that are only female height and shoe size

```
female_height = df.loc[(df[1] == 'F'), 3]
female_size = df.loc[(df[1] == 'F'), 2]
```

Here I tried to obrain rows that are only female height and shoe size

```
male_height = df.loc[(df[1] == 'M'), 3]
male_size = df.loc[(df[1] == 'M'), 2]
```

when I try to do the first plot only for female size and height I get this error:

```
sns.scatterplot(x='female_height', y='female_size', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tested the columns and it displays exactly what I need, so what is causing this error?

Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you to use first row as a column vector like below.

```
  Index Gender Size Height
0     1      F  5.5     60
1     2      F    6     60
2     3      F    7     60
3     4      F    8     60
4     5      F    8     60
5     6      F    9     60
6     7      F  7.5     60
7     8      F  6.5     60
8     9      F    5     60
```

Second, make a new df of the filter.
i.e.

```
df1 = df[df[1] == 'F']
```

Then, you can plot it with columns.

```
sns.scatterplot(x='Height', y='Size', data=df1)
```